# How to execute a function on button click with mouse movement?

Tags: linux, mouse, i3, mouse-gestures

I want the system to listen for a button press and then a mouse Right/left/up/down movement. I know which button is pressed by `XEV`, but I don’t know how to listen for mouse movements and then execute something. Does anyone know how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that you're using `Xorg` as the default X Window server you can accomplish it installing `cnee`. A simple bash script that can read the actions of left-clicking the mouse would be:

```
#!/bin/bash

mousedownFunction () {
   echo "mouse down event"
}

mouseupFunction () {
   echo "mouse up event"
}

cnee --record --mouse |
   while read line; do
      if [ ! -z "$(echo "$line" | awk  '/7,4,0,0,1/')"  ]; then
         mousedownFunction
      elif [ ! -z "$(echo "$line" | awk  '/7,5,0,0,1/')" ]; then
         mouseupFunction
      fi  
   done
```

The result is:

[image]

---

OBS: When you run the command `cnee --record --mouse` on a terminal window you'll see that it categorizes each mouse action with a specific number. On the script's example `7,4,0,0,1` represents **left-click mousedown** and `7,5,0,0,1` represents **left-click mouseup**. But **you can capture other actions as well**, as middle click, right click, mouse up/down scrolls and **mouse movements**. You just need to adapt the script to suit your needs.